# Advises for a mobile app

Tags: internet

I would like to develop a mobile application that makes it easier to make appointments with private individuals and doctors and dentists, similar to the existing solutions but with additional health information articles.

I have the application on a technological level, but I decided to call one of my childhood friends who is currently studying interactive design in Tokyo, Japan to create the graphical interface and to think with me about the ergonomics of the application.

I chose the name Doctora for the application and the name of the future company I want to create at the end of the month in Sydney, Australia.

The questions I ask myself are the following:

1. What are the different laws applicable to my application?
2. What precautions do I need to take to be 100% owner of my
   application?
3. What means can I put in place to protect my application but also the
   services and data accessible to the application?
4. How can I protect my trademark with peace of mind?

Comment: Your app idea doesn't make sense. Or are you saying you want to attract users by showing them health-related articles and then recommend that they make an appointment with a doctor or a dentist (based on the articles they've browsed and the geolocation they're in)? Study what webmd.com has done. Go to a public law library near you where they let you use lexisnexis for free. Read all the cases where webmd.com has been sued in the past. You can use Google to do the same of course, but Google will only find a tiny fraction of those court cases in question.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to, I could within an hour register a company named "Doctora" in Sydney, Australia, under my name. Except there may be problems because the name is too similar to DOCTOR A. KIRIAKOVA PTY LTD and THE CHAIR DOCTOR W.A. PTY LTD.

So question 2: "What precautions do I need to take", one is not to tell the world the planned company name. Another is not to involve childhood friends who can claim they contributed.

Comment: Or, if you do involve a third party, you include a contract which stipulates the scope of work and remuneration for that work in specific, certain terms.  And make sure to pay them that remuneration.

Answer (score -1):

> 1. What are the different laws applicable to my application?

The laws in each and every national and sub-national jurisdiction where your app is used.

> 2. What precautions do I need to take to be 100% owner of my application?

You don’t 100% own your app. The guy who designed the GUI owns that part of it subject to the contract you made with them.

> 3. What means can I put in place to protect my application but also the services and data accessible to the application?

Legal? Hire a lawyer. Technical? Hire a computer security professional.

> 4. How can I protect my trademark with peace of mind?

You can register your trademark in Australia through [IP Australia](https://www.ipaustralia.gov.au/trade-marks). You can then repeat that process for each country where you want trademark protection.